# Metodo que verifica se o status está ok

Tags: java

Tenho esse código logo abaixo que faz uma conexão com o meu servidor.
Gostaria de realizar uma verificação do status do meu servidor através de um método que faz a conexão com esse servidor, como posso implementar isso?

```
public class ConnectionRabbitmqFactoryConsumer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
        SaveLog.lauchLog(ReadConfigDatabase.class.getName());

    public static ConnectionFactory getConnection() {

        try {

            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("192.168.120.150");
            factory.setUsername("adm");
            factory.setPassword("adm");
            factory.setPort(5672);

            return factory;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            LOGGER.error("error conection rabbitmq ");
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

Essa é uma aplicação que realiza o envio de mensagem do meu server / cliente. O código abaixo, prepara o envio dessa mensagem, antes de realizar o envio ele cai nesse getConnection(), para ver se está tudo ok com o meu server.

```
    @Override
public void run() {

    try {

        //Execultar tarefas assincronas
        ExecutorService threader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        Connection connection = ConnectionRabbitmqFactoryConsumer.getConnection().newConnection(threader);
```

.......

Comment: Você quer um método para verificar se o servidor está online então?

Comment: Isso, exatamente.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o código abaixo lhe ajude:

```
public static boolean hostAvailabilityCheck() { 
    try (Socket s = new Socket("192.168.120.150", 5672)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        /* ignore */
    }
    return false;
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149882/2387977 . Recomendo visualizar o link mencionado sobre problemas relacionados a esta solução.

Comment: E no caso que eu tenho usuario e senha? como que fica? Grato